# Select row after pressing cancel in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid and an edit template that is a pop-up.

I would like that after I press Cancel on that pop-up to select the row that is edited. Using a template,I don't need to select the row for sending data to my Controller. Is it possible to get the row that is edited without being selected? I have this function :

```
 e.container.find(".k-grid-cancel").bind("click", function () {
                var row = $(e).closest("tr");
                row.select();
            })
```

Comment: can you show me your code?

Comment: @jinesh grid code?

Comment: can you print row variable in console and show me that

Comment: @Jinesh I found a solution. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with

```
var uid= e.model.uid;
e.container.find(".k-grid-cancel").bind("click", function () {
                    grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
                    grid.select('tr[data-uid="' + uid+ '"]');
                })
```